# Slightly different result data when filtering per month or all time. Which design patterns applies?

Tags: php, oop, symfony, design-patterns

So I'm creating a timeline where for the current month I calculate some KPI's to show next to the timeline. Like totals and improvement compared to last month.

When I select "All Time" I'd like to show all the same KPI's except one. The improvement compared to last month would be an average for All Time per user.

Which design pattern case I use to implement this functionality? Since both API calls to my Symfony2 backend will probably just use the same endpoint, just a different parameter MONTH vs All Time (or maybe a different end point). And they for 90% will do the same calculations I'd like to make this as generic as possible to allow maybe different parameters in the future.

Should I create a Strategy like MonthFilterStrategy and AllTimeFilterStrategy and set a context based on the parameter or is there a better design pattern which applies to this use case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create separate methods/endpoints in your controllers and bussines-layer
2. If those methods share some code move it into yet another non-public method

---

URLs:

```
http://my-domain.com/get-results/2014/06
http://my-domain.com/get-results/all-time
```

Controllers/actions:

```
public function getResultsByMonthAction($year, $month) {
    $from = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', sprintf('%d-%d-01', $year, $month));
    $from->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $to = $from->modify('next month');

    $results = $this->myService->getResultsByDateRange($from, $to);

    return $this->handleCommonCode($results);
}

public function getAllTimeResultsAction() {
    $results = $this->myService->getAllTimeResults();

    return $this->handleCommonCode($results);
}

private function handleCommonCode($results) {
    ...

    $abc = $this->processResultsSomehow($results);

    return $this->renderTemplate('...', [
        'someExtraData' => $abc,
        'results' => $results
    ]);
}
```

Service:

```
public function getResultsByDateRange(DateTime $from, DateTime $to) {
    if ($from > $to) {
        throw new LogicException('Invalid range. $from must be lower than $to.');
    }

    $criteria = [
        'date-rage' => [$from, $to]
    ];

    return $this->getResults($criteria);
}

public function getAllTimeResults() {
    return $this->getResults();
}

protected function getResults(array $criteria = []) {
    // let's assume you're quering database (using Doctrine)
    $queryBuilder = ...;

    if (isset($criteria['date-rage'])) {
         $queryBuilder
             ->andWhere('abc.someDate BETWEEN :dateRangeStart AND :dateRangeEnd')
             ->addParameters([
                  'dateRangeStart' => $criteria['date-rage'][0],
                  'dateRangeEnd'   => $criteria['date-rage'][1]
             ]);
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This approach requires a little bit more code but it comes with benefits:

1. Much easier to document and understand API,
2. No need for countless `if` statements,
3. Easier to extend/override as each part of the code is in separate method,
4. Easier debugging and maintenance,
5. Each method can contain some individual logic,
6. Support from 3rd-party tools (IDEs, code analizers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that if there are no params with which to scope the date, you'd apply your calculations across N months, where N is some sane limit (or not; YMMV). Given that, the processing should happen on N months of data and never presume that there could only be a single object to process. Always assume you'll be processing N months of data and then let the existence of scoping/filtering params go on to drive the UI.